# Playing media from https site in media element throwing null reference exception in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to Play video from https site into my media element throwing the following exception.

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

This is my code in xmal

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual"  Stretch="Fill" Loaded="OnMediaElementLoaded" MediaOpened="MediaElement_OnMediaOpened" />

var uri = new Uri("https://f60b7719060a37f20253-4343910d3bf76239b8a83e4f56d17dc5.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/mov-2015-06-07-22-08-09-391574e61009867cfcb1a1641639b39e55c8a34c.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
mediaElement.Source = uri;
mediaElement.Play();//Getting exception here.
```

Any help please? I also tried the same using the some other http.

Comment: At which point in your code does this exception arise ?

Comment: in  mediaElement.Play(); i am getting this exception

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question per se, but it does explain how to use MediaElement: http://pmichaels.net/2015/03/01/playing-media-in-windows-universal-apps/

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to make a wpf MediaElement play when its Source is a https uri](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51431493/774575). `MediaElement` doesn't support authentication. Before going to other solutions, try accessing the resource with `http`, the server may serve the file without encryption, if The Force is with you.

Answer (score 9):

Commentators are trying to look smart by giving completely irrelevant information, but the MediaElement, in fact, can't play from HTTPS sources, a [bug that has been acknowledged and not prioritized enough to get fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/934355/in-a-wpf-standalone-application-exe-when-the-source-of-a-mediaelement-is-set-to-a-https-uri-it-throws-a-nullreferenceexception).

You will either have to supply a non-HTTPS source url or save the content to file first and then load it (can be accomplished with a virtualized file system).

Answer (score -1):

I just found a way to do it using Universal Windows Platform (UWP). This solution successfully plays video with a MediaElement from an https source.  The implementation is similar to yours except it creates a stream from the URI and sets that as the MediaElement source.  Credit to https://github.com/kiewic .

https://github.com/kiewic/MediaElementWithHttpClient

```
MediaElement mediaPlayer = new MediaElement();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Uri uri = new Uri("https://f60b7719060a37f20253-4343910d3bf76239b8a83e4f56d17dc5.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/mov-2015-06-07-22-08-09-391574e61009867cfcb1a1641639b39e55c8a34c.mp4");
HttpRandomAccessStream stream = await HttpRandomAccessStream.CreateAsync(client, uri);

mediaPlayer.SetSource(stream, "video/mp4");
```

Comment: The question title clearly specifies WPF.